# Feed API to display RSS feeds Ted talk

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, rss

I am trying to create a webpage that will read RSS feeds from the TED talk website and display it on a page. I am using Google's Feed API for this.

[Here](http://challengereceived.netii.net) is the link to view the code online.

Could someone please tell me if there is a better way to display the data coming from the feed?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates and open the template in the editor. -->
<head>
    <title>TED Talks Google Feed API</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/google.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <h1>Welcome to the Ted talks Feed</h1>
   <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Feed API (JavaScript)**

```
  google.load("feeds", "1");
    // Our callback function, for when a feed is loaded.
    function feedLoaded(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                var link = '<a target=_blank; href="' + entry.link + '">' + 'View on Ted.com' + '</a>';
                var image = result.feed.entries[i].mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url;
                $(".inner").append('<div class="innerdetail viewmore" data-num="'+ i +'"> <img class="thumbnail" title="Click to view more" src="'+ image +'"/> <p class="title">'+ entry.title +' </p> <p class="snippet">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p>'+ link + ' </div>');
        }

//On click of the thumbnail(Image), we will display more data with more metadata. 
    $(".thumbnail").click(function() {

    //Removing all arrows before initializing
        $(".arrow-up").remove();
        var parentClass = $(this).parent();

        //Checking to see if the parent class already is expanded or not
        if ($(parentClass).hasClass( "expandedMain" ) ) {
                $("div").removeClass("expandedMain");
                $(".expandedView").remove();
                $(".arrow-up").remove();
            }
            else{
                $(".arrow-up").show();
                $("div").removeClass("expandedMain");
                $(this).parent().addClass("expandedMain");
                var plant = $(this).parent();
                var DataCount = plant[0].dataset.num;
                var entry = result.feed.entries[DataCount];

            //Appending the cideo in a variable for use later
                var video = '<video class="video" width="480" height="320" controls> <source src="'+ entry.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url +'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
                $(plant).append('<div class="arrow-up"></div> <div class="expandedView" data-category="'+ entry.categories[0] +'"><p class="title">'+ entry.title +' </p>' + video + '<p class="publishedDate">Published Date:'+ entry.publishedDate +' <p> <p class="fullcontent">' + entry.content + '</p></div>');
                $(".expandedView").show(1000);
            }
           });
        }
    }

//On Load event
    function OnLoad() {
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/tedtalks_video");
        feed.includeHistoricalEntries(); // tell the API we want to have old entries too
        feed.setNumEntries(250); // we want a maximum of 250 entries, if they exist

    // Calling load sends the request off.  It requires a callback function.
        feed.load(feedLoaded);
}

     google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

**CSS:**

```
 h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Raleway', arial, sans-serif;
        }
        a{
            font-family: 'Raleway', arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.75em;
        }
     #content{
        background: #e1e1e1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .thumbnail{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 200px;
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 150px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .innerdetail{
        width: 200px;
        display: inline-table;
        height: auto;
        margin: 1em;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
        padding: 1em;
        background-color: ghostwhite;
    }

    .title, .publishedDate{
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
    }

    .snippet, .fullcontent{
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
    }

    .expandedView{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        height: auto;
        left: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        transition: 1s ease;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 1em;
        z-index: 1000;
        cursor: default;
        display: none;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px black;
    }

    .expandedView .title, .expandedView .publishedDate{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .expandedView .title{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .expandedMain{
        height: 600px;
    }

    .video{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .inner{
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .close{
        z-index: 1001;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .arrow-up {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid gray; 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple things you could improve here.  First, you should specify a character encoding for the document, like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
```

Next, your indentation is erratic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates and open the template in the editor. -->
<head>
    <title>TED Talks Google Feed API</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/google.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <h1>Welcome to the Ted talks Feed</h1>
   <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This should be indented like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates and open the template in the editor. -->
<head>
    <title>TED Talks Google Feed API</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/google.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <h1>Welcome to the Ted talks Feed</h1>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The indentation on your CSS and JS is also erratic.

One excellent thing is that your HTML and CSS validates to the W3C validators:

> [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)
>   [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Your JS does not validate at [JSLint](http://jslint.com) because your indentation is off.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation. I completely missed that in a hurry.

Answer (score 5):

As [@Hosch250](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/34073/hosch250) pointed out, this is hard to read because the indentation is off in many places.

A minor thing about this loop:

> ```
>       for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
>           var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
>           var link = '<a target=_blank; href="' + entry.link + '">' + 'View on Ted.com' + '</a>';
>           var image = result.feed.entries[i].mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url;
>           $(".inner").append('<div class="innerdetail viewmore" data-num="' + i + '"> <img class="thumbnail" title="Click to view more" src="' + image + '"/> <p class="title">' + entry.title + ' </p> <p class="snippet">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p>' + link + ' </div>');
>       }
> ```

The `$(".inner")` dom lookup will be performed in every iteration of the loop,
which is inefficient.
It would be better to cache this lookup in a variable before the loop:

```
      var $inner = $(".inner");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
          var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
          var link = '<a target=_blank; href="' + entry.link + '">' + 'View on Ted.com' + '</a>';
          var image = result.feed.entries[i].mediaGroups[0].contents[0].thumbnails[0].url;
          $inner.append('<div class="innerdetail viewmore" data-num="' + i + '"> <img class="thumbnail" title="Click to view more" src="' + image + '"/> <p class="title">' + entry.title + ' </p> <p class="snippet">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p>' + link + ' </div>');
      }
```